# VSCODE autocompletion can't find class Slider into module matplotlib.widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pylint

As per the title, though the module is correctly pinpointed (`matplotlib.widgets`), the class `Slider` and other ones inside it (that **are present**, confirmed by the python script accessed through `CTRL+LEFT_CLICK`) are not found by IntelliSence (`Pylance`): only `SubplotTool` and `Widget` classes are available (see image below).

[image]

The script runs correctly as expected but I have no clues of the code auto-completion. I tried adding an `extraPath` to `python.autoComplete` and `python.analysis` options even though I was aware the path was correctly handled by IntelliSense and PyLint .

I'm not able to even understand where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late, it looks like was caused by the `Pylance Language Server`, switching to `Jedi` can solve it temporarily, but I don't think you will like it:

```
"python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

I will submit a bug on Pylance.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2066